# Tracy Widom type results for asymptotic distribution of the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of the sample covariance when $n, p \to \infty$?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices, random-walks

Earlier I asked a question: [Distribution of the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of in the sample covariance matrix?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354274/distribution-of-the-k-th-largest-eigenvalue-of-in-the-sample-covariance-matrix), but I forgot to mention that I'd like results for asymtotic regime. So, I'm posting here a modified question.

I'm new to random matrix theory, but per my understanding [Tracy-Widom law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy%E2%80%93Widom_distribution) describes the the asymptotic distribution of the largest eigenvalue of any square real symmetrix matrix with iid entries on the diagonal and above it, of dimension $n \times n$ as $n \to \infty$. (Please correct me if I'm wrong!).

What I'm trying to do is to connect, or at least find a resource that connect Tracy-Widom with [Marcenko-Pastur law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) in a somewhat detailed way, as follows.

Let us assume we've a rectangular data matrix $X=[x_1 \dots x_n] \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$, where the $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$ are iid column vectors. I'm not assuming here that the entries of the matrix $X$ are iid, but if you so need to answer the question, you can assume that first, and then perhaps we can see what happens when we put a covariance structure on $X$. Let, as often in the random matrix domain, let $n, p \to \infty, p/n \to c \in (0, \infty)$.I'm interested in the limiting distribution of $k$-th largest eigenvalue, when $k$ is fixed and $k$ - is varying.

**Precisely, my questions are:**

(1) What's the limiting distruition of the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{p}XX^{T}$, as $p, n \to \infty, p/n \to c?$

(2) Also what's the limiting distribution of the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{p}XX^{T}$, as $k, p, n \to \infty, p/n \to c, k/p \to c', c\in (0, \infty), c' \in (0,1) ?$

To show you an idea what I'm after, I'll mentiong what I found from my search:

(1)I found this paper that seems to be relevant: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aoap/1481792600, but they deal with the the limiting distribution of the largest eigenvalue.

(2) This paper by Tracy and Widom: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9211141.pdf, describes in Section E the probability density for the $k$-th largest eigenvalue. But I think *there the underlying matrix is a real (or complex) symmetric (or Hermitian) matrix with iid entries on the diagonal and above the diagonal, and **not** sample covariance matrix.*

Any help will be sincerely appreciated, as I'm super new to RMT!